# glXCreateWindow doesn't work when VISUAL_ID and screen->root_visual aren't equal

Tags: c++, c, x11, glx, xcb

I'm working on code very similar to this:

http://xcb.freedesktop.org/opengl/

It works fine when I use the default framebuffer configuration, although when I try to query a certain one it fails. I've determined that it fails whenever `VISUAL_ID` (`visualID` in the example code) and `screen->root_visual` are different values.

Here is the error message:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  135 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  31 (X_GLXCreateWindow)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x1600003
  Serial number of failed request:  32
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Invalid visual ID would normally produce a `BadMatch` error, not a `BadWindow`. Please show your code.

Comment: @n.m. I get the same crash with the posted link's code when using certain framebuffer configurations other than the first (`[0]`)

Answer (score 2):

The most likely event is that `xcb_create_window()` call fails (use `xcb_create_window_checked()` and `xcb_request_check()` to verify that). It fails because `COPY_FROM_PARENT` is specified as the depth, which doesn't match the required visual depth.

You should query the depth of the visual you are using, and pas it to `xcb_create_window()`.

**UPDATE** If you create a window of a depth different from its parent, you have to specify the border pixel, and probably also the background pixel and the colormap, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3645632/775806).

Comment: I can confirm that `xcb_request_check` is returning an error, but I do not know what to do with it. I tried getting a depth value with `glXGetFBConfigAttrib(display` but am still getting the error.

Comment: See update in the answer. Also, if you use `GLX_DEPTH_SIZE`, it's wrong (it's the size of the *depth buffer*). `GLX_BUFFER_SIZE` could be wrong too (it's not necessarily equal to the depth in terms of the X server). I think one should use `XGetVisualInfo`, or whatever is the `xcb` equivalent.