# Fixing a window onto the top of window stack in XCB

Tags: x11, xcb

I wanted to know if there is any method or code available to fix a particular window (say for example a newly created window) on to the top of the window stack in xcb, so that Alt+Tab is completely disabled from that window, i.e, Alt+Tab works only with other windows in the stack except the top window ?

I am using code of xcb from here:

https://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/basicwindowsanddrawing/

I referred to the below link for setting the window on to the top of the stack, but when I press Alt+Tab, the other windows pop up onto the screen.

https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libxcb/tutorial/index.html#winstack

So, is there a way to stop the Alt+Tab from associating from the top window, and only with the lower windows ?

Comment: Does [XComposite Composite Overlay Window](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/Xcomposite.3.html) do what you want?

Comment: Do not use links which can get corrupted over time and question become useless for others.

Comment: @Rarblack Agreed, but how does it apply to this link? Xorg will outlive SO anyway. Also, the description of the link is good enough for any search engine to find. Looking forward to your thoughts.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the link. I will look into it and come back if it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as @Andreas had pointed out, I used the provided link for XComposite Overlay Window and was able to setup a window at the top of all other windows and Alt+Tab was associated only with the lower windows.

I also referred to this question for writing the code : [X11 - Draw on Overlay Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780789/x11-draw-on-overlay-window)

Thing is that I tested this code on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it worked for me.

Thanks.