# Overlay Window in x11 keeps Flickering

Tags: c, overlay, x11, cairo

I adopted the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780789/x11-draw-on-overlay-window) answer in order to draw an overlay window, which stays on top of all windows, always. But I find that this window keeps flickering whenever there is a keypress or a button click. I wanted to know if this can be stopped somehow. Increasing the time did not help me, as my terminal was frozen for few seconds when I increased time to `5000000000`

The code was tested on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**.

Comment: So... you have some code, which opens up a new window, draws to it and then hides the window again (=makes the content below it visible again). Possibly 200 times per second. And you ask why this flickers. Did I understand that correctly? If so, would you accept an answer saying "because you release the overlay window, which means your drawings disappear all the time"? (No, I do not know what this has to do with keypresses or buttonpresses.)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. You have understood my question rightly. And as per the comment, I tried removing the `XCompositeReleaseOverlayWindow()` from the loop. But it still flickers. In fact, apart from drawing the overlay, I have another process running within the loop (something that requires a good amount of computation). So is that the reason for this flickering ?

Comment: Well, I can only guess. My next guess would be that you are using a compositing manager that also uses the overlay window and whenever the compositing manager redraws the screen, your overlay is erased. But these are all guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a solution using the `XComposite` suite of functions. However, you can easily achieve the same effect with (in my opinion) much more flexibility and pure X11 via `CWOverrideRedirect`. You can see example usage for it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57780772/4204557

Comment: This method was really spot on. I was successfully able to place the X window on to the top and neither Alt+Tab nor clicking on other icons brought other windows over it. Thanks a lot!!