# Shadows on windows with a bit depth of 32

Tags: x11, xlib, xcb

In my reparenting window manager, I reparent windows to frames with the same bit depth:

```rs
let geom = self.conn.get_geometry(ev.window)?.reply()?;
        let attr = self.conn.get_window_attributes(ev.window)?.reply()?;
        let frame_win = self.conn.generate_id()?;
        let win_aux = xproto::CreateWindowAux::new()
            .event_mask(
                xproto::EventMask::EXPOSURE
                    | xproto::EventMask::SUBSTRUCTURE_REDIRECT
                    | xproto::EventMask::SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY
                    | xproto::EventMask::BUTTON_PRESS
                    | xproto::EventMask::BUTTON_RELEASE
                    | xproto::EventMask::POINTER_MOTION
                    | xproto::EventMask::ENTER_WINDOW
                    | xproto::EventMask::PROPERTY_CHANGE,
            )
            .background_pixel(self.config.background_pixel)
            .border_pixel(self.config.border_pixel)
            .colormap(attr.colormap);
        self.conn.create_window(
            geom.depth,
            frame_win,
            screen.root,
            geom.x,
            geom.y,
            geom.width,
            geom.height + self.config.title_height as u16,
            self.config.border_width as u16,
            xproto::WindowClass::INPUT_OUTPUT,
            attr.visual,
            &win_aux,
        )?;
```

However, when the bit depth of the inside window and therefore the frame is 32, compositors do not draw shadows around the frame. If it has another depth like 24 they do. why would this happen?

Comment: No idea. Which compositor are you using? My suggestion would be to check that compositor for when it does / does not draw shadows. A random guess would be: It assumes that depth=32 windows have transparent parts and shadows would look ugly with that, so it just does not draw any shadows in this case.

Comment: Oh, you're right, xcompmgr does that; I tested it with picom and it works. So not my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `xcompmgr` just doesn't composite windows with a depth of 32. Picom and Compton work fine. Maybe there's some setting to change that; at any rate, there's nothing the wm can do about it.